# Install pgAdmin on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS - Conf pgadmin4 does not exist

Tags: ubuntu, pgadmin, ubuntu-20.04

I'm running these commands to install pgAdmin on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

```
#
# Setup the repository
#

# Install the public key for the repository (if not done previously):
sudo curl https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo apt-key add

# Create the repository configuration file:
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'

#
# Install pgAdmin
#

# Install for both desktop and web modes:
sudo apt install pgadmin4

# Install for desktop mode only:
sudo apt install pgadmin4-desktop

# Install for web mode only: 
sudo apt install pgadmin4-web 

# Configure the webserver, if you installed pgadmin4-web:
sudo /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh
```

https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/

Everything proceed smoothly until I launch this command:

`sudo /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh`

Which produces this output:

```
Creating configuration database...
pgAdmin 4 - Application Initialisation
======================================

Creating storage and log directories...
We can now configure the Apache Web server for you. This involves enabling the wsgi module and configuring the pgAdmin 4 application to mount at /pgadmin4. Do you wish to continue (y/n)? y
ERROR: Conf pgadmin4 does not exist!
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by running:

```
sudo apt install libgmp3-dev libpq-dev libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

Then set up again:

```
sudo /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh
```